# Is there a way to get access_key and secret_key from boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

When I launch an EC2 instance with an IAM role I can use `boto3` on that EC2instance and not have to specify aws access and secret keys because `boto3` [reads them automatically](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#iam-role).

```
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
>>> list(s3.buckets.all())[0]
s3.Bucket(name='my-bucket-name')
```

**Question**

I'm wondering if there is any way to get the access key and secret key from boto3? For example, how can I print them on to the standard console using `print`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There sure is ([docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.get_credentials)):

```
from boto3 import Session

session = Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
# Credentials are refreshable, so accessing your access key / secret key
# separately can lead to a race condition. Use this to get an actual matched
# set.
current_credentials = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()

# I would not recommend actually printing these. Generally unsafe.
print(current_credentials.access_key)
print(current_credentials.secret_key)
print(current_credentials.token)
```

Comment: Good mention of 'get_frozen_credentials', method, which isn't mentioned in the already answered question referenced above.

Comment: doubt: without passing credentials to 'Session` how does `boto3` know which credentials to return? or from which account the credentials it should return?

Comment: To answer Kishor Pawar's question above, the call above to session would need to include the profile name in the config file. For example, I'm using: 

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='namexyz') where 'namexyz' is the section in my credentials file: [namexyz].